# CSS specificity and cascade

Tags: css

```
<style>
  .floated div{
    float: left;
  }
</style>
<div class="floated">
  <div class="box-1">1</div>
  <div class="box-2">2</div>
  <div class="box-3">3</div>
</div>
```

So I have been playing with css lately and
if i took out "div" in the .floated div part,
the result is different, resulting in the 3 div boxes lining up as a column. Where as if I keep the div part as .floated div, the three boxes stay next to each other. So why does specifying div result in a different result?

Comment: If you keep div in the above code, you're applying float left to box-1,2 and 3 not .floated

Comment: but isn't class more specific so they have more power than div?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what specificity actually means. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity: _“Specificity only applies when the same element is targeted by multiple declarations.”_ - that is not even the case here.

Comment: space in selector part selects all children regardless of level but not the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

i think when you just style .floated it is applied just to the outer div i.e only the outer container is floated to left
whereas applying styling "div" too applies the float:left property to inner divs also i.e they are stacked together

Comment: Don't say _inner divs also_. Say only inner divs.

Answer (score 0):

It happens as `float` takes your element from the normal flow of the page.

As [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) says:

> The float CSS property places an element on the left or right side of
> its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it.
> The element is removed from the normal flow of the page, though still
> remaining a part of the flow (in contrast to absolute positioning).